# Configuring LucidWorks Include Paths to only crawl certain file types

Tags: regex, web-crawler, lucidworks

I'm trying to configure the LucidWorks web data source to only index certain file types. However, when I set *Include paths* to `.*\.html` to only crawl .html files (as a simplified example), it only ends up indexing the top level folder.  *Crawl depth* is set to `-1` and when I leave *Include paths* blank, it crawls the whole sub-tree as expected.

I've looked at their documentation for [creating a web data source](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug20/Create+a+New+Web+Data+Source), and for [Using Regular Expressions](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/help/Using+Regular+Expressions), and can't find a reason why `.*\.html` would not work, since `.*` should match any character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As I was proofreading the question, I had an idea which was the correct solution. Posting it here for posterity.*

---

The content being crawled is a file share, so it relies on directory listing of the web server, which was filtered out because it doesn't have a .html extension. So simply adding `.*/` to the *Include paths* fixed the problem.